# how to get SymPy to replace ints like 1.0 with 1

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

Sorry for the newbie question but I have not found the answer elsewhere so far.

Say we have a symbol and we multiply it by the float number one:

```
import sympy

x = sympy.Symbol('x')
x = 1.0 * x
```

All the expressions that contain this `x` will also contain factor one whatever I do:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(x)
pprint(sympy.simplify(x))
```

Output:

```
1.0⋅x
1.0⋅x
```

In the example above, I want to output `x` instead of `1.0⋅x`. Is it possible to simplify the expression in the way that it solves all multiplications by a float number one? Should I transform this float number to another datatype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's due to the floating-point vs integer 1 - don't use 1.0 if you can get away with 1, perhaps?

You could check if it's identically 1.0 with `if f.as_integer_ratio() == (1, 1)`, and if so don't prepend the unnecessary '1.0':

```
>>> xf = 1.0 * x
>>> xi = 1 * x

>>> xf
1.0*x
>>> xi
x

>>> pprint(xf)
1.0*x
>>> pprint(xi)
x
```

It might be due to floating-point inexactness (I don't know sympy much, can't say more).

EDIT: the runtime of `float.as_integer_ratio()` is tiny, in response to your question:

```
>>> python -m timeit -n 1000000 '(1.0).as_integer_ratio() == (1,1)'
1000000 loops, best of 5: 172 nsec per loop

>>> python -m timeit -n 1000000 '(1.1).as_integer_ratio() == (1,1)'
1000000 loops, best of 5: 327 nsec per loop

>>> python -m timeit -n 1000000 '(1.01).as_integer_ratio() == (1,1)'
1000000 loops, best of 5: 331 nsec per loop

>>> python -m timeit -n 1000000 '(0.999999999999).as_integer_ratio() == (1,1)'
1000000 loops, best of 5: 329 nsec per loop
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't really cast it to int, because sometimes it is a float number that is not equal one. But when it is, I wanna simplify. Maybe the way to go is to check whether it is equal one using if statement. The later looks a little bit dirty to me.

Comment: Well you can check if it's identically 1.0 with `if f.as_integer_ratio() == (1, 1)`

Comment: Is it a time-consuming function? What do you feel?

Comment: What, comparing `float.as_integer_ratio()` to e.g. `sympy.simplify.simplify.nsimplify(..., tolerance)`? I doubt their runtime matters at all. You could tweak `tolerance` if you like.

Comment: @freude: I measured the runtime with timeit, and confirm it's tiny.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution. There is a special function [`nsimplify()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#sympy.simplify.simplify.nsimplify)  that does the job.

Answer (score 1):

If `nsimplify` is more aggressive that you intend -- it will simplify Floats to values that are *close* but not exactly the same -- then you might consider the following function which will only target integers expressed as Floats.

```
>>> def flint(eq):
...     """convert floats that are ints to ints"""
...     reps = {}
...     e = eq.replace(
...         lambda x: x.is_Float and x == int(x),
...         lambda x: reps.setdefault(x, Dummy()))
...     return e.xreplace({v: int(k) for k, v in reps.items()})
>>> flint(1.0*x)
x
>>> flint(1.0*x+x**2.0)
x**2 + x
```